# Trying to write vectorised dirac symbols in overleaf

Tags: braket, scientific-notation

Trying to write a vectorised symbol in overleaf that should look like `|a>>` in dirac notation, but not at all sure how to get either the individual > dirac symbol or do two automatically. Doing `\ket{\ket{a}}` gives `||a>>` which is not quite right. Trying to make it look like eq.11 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0606035.pdf:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

Comment: I'll just add that you can use `\rangle`. I found it on https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the delimiters to scale like for the `\ket` command of `braket`, you might define

```
\newcommand{\kett}[1]{\mathopen|#1\rangle\!\rangle}
```

Well, the paper authors define

```
\newcommand{\kett}[1]{\vert#1\rangle\!\rangle}
```

(curiously, I chose `\kett` for the name before looking at the source for the article).

Now the input

```
\begin{equation}
A\otimes B\kett{C} = \kett{ACB^T}
\end{equation}
```

will produce

[image]

Trust me, `\mathopen|` is better than `\vert` in this context. An equivalent command could be `\lvert` if you load `amsmath` (as you likely should).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm not particularly experienced in LaTeX and am still ironing out all the little skills.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, egreg gives a better and more thorough answer, but in general if you are curious about how an article on arXiv.org implements something, there's a way to do it:

You can download the [source](https://arxiv.org/e-print/quant-ph/0606035v1) by clicking on the ["other formats"](https://arxiv.org/format/quant-ph/0606035v1) option in the right column, which gives you a `.tar.gz` file (you have to add this file ending manually). Unpacking it, we get a directory, and the tex file defines the following macros which seem to be what you're looking for:

```
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\vert}
\newcommand{\ketsub}[2]{\vert#1\rangle_#2}
\newcommand{\brasub}[2]{\!\,_#2\!\langle#1\vert}
%\newcommand{\kett}[1]{ \left.\left\vert#1\right\rangle\!\right\rangle}
%\newcommand{\braa}[1]{\left\langle\!\left\langle#1\right\vert\right.}
\newcommand{\kett}[1]{\vert#1\rangle\!\rangle}
\newcommand{\braa}[1]{\langle\!\langle#1\vert}
\newcommand{\braakett}[2]{\langle\!\langle#1\vert#2\rangle\!\rangle}
```

Comment: Thanks a heap, this will save me loads of time in the future!